# Validation message wont appear when using onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code for a simple jQuery validation. However I want the validation to appear if the field is left empty and the add task button is clicked. At the minute it appears all the time. This form is to add a to do item to a list so will be blank once loaded

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AddTask').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#title').val() == '') {
      $(this).next('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
      $(this).next('.errorMsg').hide();
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#todo").hide(); //hide form until create new task button is clicked 
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new").on('click', function() {
   $("#todo").toggle();
  $("#new").hide();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#AddTask").click(function() {
    $("#todo").slideUp("slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  $("#new").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Title of Task</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
<span class="errorMsg">Title of task required </span>

<button type="required" id="AddTask">Add Task</button>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `$(document).ready(...)` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).next` will look for the next element after the button where as your error message is before the button. Instead use`classIdentifier` and you need to hide the message initially.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AddTask').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#title').val() == '') {
      $('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
      $('.errorMsg').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.errorMsg{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Title of Task</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
<span class="errorMsg">Title of task required </span>

<button type="required" id="AddTask">Add Task</button>
```

**P.S.** Instead of `next` if you have used `prev` it would have worked but I'll suggest going with `classIdentifier` only there is no need of `prev` for this particular code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AddTask').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#title').val() == '') {
      $(this).prev('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
      $(this).prev('.errorMsg').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.errorMsg{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Title of Task</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
<span class="errorMsg">Title of task required </span>

<button type="required" id="AddTask">Add Task</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$(this).next` simply use `$('your-error-class).show().html('error you want to show');`

Secondly you are using `$(this).next()` wrong.

It will look for the next element after the button to be your error class which is not actually present there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide the `.errorMsg` first using css `display: none;` , also use `$(".errorMsg")` selector.

I have also updated the `id` for input since you are using the `label` for same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AddTask').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#exampleFormControlInput1').val() === '') {
      $('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
      $('.errorMsg').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.errorMsg{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Title of Task</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Title">
<span class="errorMsg">Title of task required </span>

<button type="required" id="AddTask">Add Task</button>
```

Comment: This worked, however is there any way I can stop the form from sliding up until the form is complete. At the minute the validation message appears but the form still slides up. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Just slide up your form when you don't have error message, I guess that will be when your input is non-empty. But its better to create a function which keep tracks of form submit, explore that as an additional.

Answer (score 1):

For detect if `input` is empty or not better use `length` like this:

```
if ($('#title').val().length <= 0) {
  $(this).prev('.errorMsg').show();
} else {
  $(this).prev('.errorMsg').hide();
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkmet7pk/)**

Comment: validation message is still appearing once form is loaded

Comment: @Smith check my answer :)